# Running Jest/Babel and getting the error Cannot find module

Tags: angular, jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

I recently started configuring Jest with Babel so we can run tests for our Angular code. I'm running into an error I can quite find a configuration for.

```
src/app/admin/metamodel/icon-viewer.component.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'ctm-common' from 'src/app/admin/metamodel/icon-viewer.component.ts'

    Require stack:
      src/app/admin/metamodel/icon-viewer.component.ts
      src/app/admin/metamodel/icon-viewer.component.spec.ts

      1 | import {ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnChanges, Output, SimpleChanges} from '@angular/core';
    > 2 | import {ComponentType, ConfigurationService, IconInfo} from "ctm-common";
        | ^
      3 | import {EditorMode} from "./editors/model/editor-data";
      4 | import { DomSanitizer, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';
      5 |

      at Resolver._throwModNotFoundError (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:427:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/admin/metamodel/icon-viewer.component.ts:2:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/admin/metamodel/icon-viewer.component.spec.ts:3:1)
```

Zeroing in on the line

```
import {ComponentType, ConfigurationService, IconInfo} from "ctm-common";
```

This is a configured path we have in our tsconfig.json

Below is the configured path in our `tsconfig.json`. I have omitted most of the other details since I believe they are irrelevant.

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        ...
    },
    "compilerOptions": {
        ....,
        "paths": {
            "ctm-common": [
                "app/+common"
            ],
            "ctm-shared": [
                "app/+shared"
            ],
            "ctm-store": [
                "app/+store"
            ],
            "ctm-store/*": [
                "app/+store/*"
            ]
        }
        .....
}
```

I'm guessing there is a configuration I need to include this somewhere but I'm not sure where exactly. Below are my test files.

`jest.config.ts`:

```
import type {Config} from 'jest';

const config: Config = {

  preset: 'jest-preset-angular',

  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)?$': 'jest-preset-angular',
    "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": 'babel-jest'

  },

  transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/?!@angular'],

  moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", "src"],
};

export default config;
```

`babel.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  
  presets: [
    '@babel/preset-env', 
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ]
}
```

The `package.json` includes the folowing under scripts:

```
"scripts": {
        ...
        "test": "jest",
        "test:watch": "jest --watch",
        ...
}
```